# How to fix malloc failure error of openssl?

Tags: linux, openssl

I am using openssl to encrypt file and I am getting malloc error as shown below.

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016

openssl command
openssl cms -sign -in infile -signer file.crt.pem -inkey file.key.pem -CAfile CAfile -out outfile -keyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -certfile by_hash/81908841

Errors
1435735688:error:2E0A40AF:CMS routines:CMS_add0_cert:certificate already present:cms_lib.c:462:
1435735688:error:2E094041:CMS routines:CMS_sign:malloc failure:cms_smime.c:461:
```

Please note that I am 100% sure that the parameters which I have provided is 100% correct, (i.e. infile, outfile, certfile, keyfile, cafile and hash_file)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> How to fix malloc failure error of openssl?

If I am parsing things correctly, it looks like `CMS_add1_cert` is failing. It may not be a memory error (or it may be due to a parsing bug causing an extremely large size parameter).

OpenSSL 1.0.2.j is [Commit e216bf9d7ca7](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/e216bf9d7ca7). Here is [`cms.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e216bf9d7ca7/apps/cms.c), and the function at [`cms_smime.c:461`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e216bf9d7ca7/crypto/cms/cms_smime.c) is shown below.

Line 461 is the code:

```
merr:
    CMSerr(CMS_F_CMS_SIGN, ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE);
```

I'm guessing it comes from this:

```
for (i = 0; i < sk_X509_num(certs); i++) {
    X509 *x = sk_X509_value(certs, i);
    if (!CMS_add1_cert(cms, x))
        goto merr;
}
```

We can't really say more because there is not enough information, like the certificates and other parameters. Your next step is install symbols and then step the code under the debugger.

---

Here is `CMS_sign`, which provides the function returning the error.

```
CMS_ContentInfo *CMS_sign(X509 *signcert, EVP_PKEY *pkey,
                          STACK_OF(X509) *certs, BIO *data,
                          unsigned int flags)
{
    CMS_ContentInfo *cms;
    int i;

    cms = CMS_ContentInfo_new();
    if (!cms || !CMS_SignedData_init(cms))
        goto merr;

    if (pkey && !CMS_add1_signer(cms, signcert, pkey, NULL, flags)) {
        CMSerr(CMS_F_CMS_SIGN, CMS_R_ADD_SIGNER_ERROR);
        goto err;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sk_X509_num(certs); i++) {
        X509 *x = sk_X509_value(certs, i);
        if (!CMS_add1_cert(cms, x))
            goto merr;
    }

    if (!(flags & CMS_DETACHED))
        CMS_set_detached(cms, 0);

    if ((flags & (CMS_STREAM | CMS_PARTIAL))
        || CMS_final(cms, data, NULL, flags))
        return cms;
    else
        goto err;

 merr:
    CMSerr(CMS_F_CMS_SIGN, ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE);

 err:
    if (cms)
        CMS_ContentInfo_free(cms);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have also checked this code and thought of putting debugging statements but problem is issue can be seen only in client environment not locally, so can't take risk to disturb openssl there, Thanks :)